# How can I change the username

Tags: username

```
zadsfad@ubuntu
```

How can I change the username (zadsfad)? If I change the host name, the 'ubuntu' section is changed.

Should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, make sure you have root login access, from a root shell prompt, type

`usermod -l **new_username** -m -d /home/**new_username** **current_username**`

then exit and re-login, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I solved it. This is answer.

Comment: I get user is currently used by process 1606